# div positioning is messed up

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have following setup:

```
.calender-month{
    float:left;
}
.buttondiv{
    float:left;
}

<div class="buttondiv"><button id="backbtn">back</button>
<div class="calender-month">calender</div>
<div class="buttondiv"><button id="frontbtn">front</button></div>
```

Initially, I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hrishikeshp19/g6s76/2/).

After trying adding buttons as mentioned above, I get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hrishikeshp19/g6s76/1/).

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add clear:both; to your calendar div CSS

```
#calender {clear:both;}
```

This will bump the calendar block below the buttons if this is what you are looking for